# my programm run properly one time but second time error 13

Tags: vba, excel-2010

My programm looks for a list of data from Sheets1 into sheets2 or Sheets3 depends on request in sheets1
the programm run properly when the source of research has a range with 2 columns
but with more then 2 columns at the program run only one time at the second time error 13 appears.
please find attached the programm.
thanks for your help
Tarik

```vb
Sub Plan_med()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim ColumnA As Range
    Dim ColumnB As Range
    Dim ColumnC As Range
    Dim F2 As Range
    Dim DernligneA As Long
    Dim DernligneB As Long
    Dim DernligneC As Long
    Dim DernlistA As Long
    Dim DernlistB As Long
    Dim DernlistC As Long
    Dim Dernlist As Long
    Dim Dernligne As Long
    Dim Medecin As String
    Dim Caserne As String
    Dim INTERV As String
    Dim N As Long
    
    
    Sheets("Feuil1").Range("L1:Z150").Clear
    
    N = Sheets("Feuil1").Range("D5")
    Medecin = Sheets("Feuil1").Range("E5")
    Caserne = Sheets("Feuil1").Range("C5")
    INTERV = Sheets("Feuil1").Range("B5")
    
    Sheets("Feuil1").Range("D5").Value = N 'inutile car redondant
    
    
    If Sheets("feuil1").Range("B5") = "ITJ" Then
    Fichier = "INT JOUR"
        Else: Fichier = "INT NUIT"
    End If
    
    DernlistA = Sheets(Fichier).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    DernlistB = Sheets(Fichier).Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    DernlistC = Sheets(Fichier).Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    DernligneA = Sheets(Fichier).Range("C3").End(xlDown).Rows + 1
    DernligneB = Sheets(Fichier).Range("G3").End(xlDown).Rows + 1
    DernligneC = Sheets(Fichier).Range("K3").End(xlDown).Rows + 1
      
      
    If Sheets("feuil1").Range("C5") = "CASERNE 1" Then
    Dernlist = DernlistA
    Set ColumnA = Sheets(Fichier).Range("A2:C" & DernligneA)
    Set F2 = Sheets(Fichier).Range("A1:A" & DernlistA)
    Dernligne = DernligneA
    End If
    If Sheets("feuil1").Range("C5") = "CASERNE 2" Then
    Dernlist = DernlistB
    Set ColumnA = Sheets(Fichier).Range("E2:G" & DernligneB)
    Set F2 = Sheets(Fichier).Range("E1:E" & DernlistB)
    Dernligne = DernligneB
    End If
    If Sheets("feuil1").Range("C5") = "CASERNE 3" Then
    Dernlist = DernlistC
    Set ColumnA = Sheets(Fichier).Range("I2:K" & DernligneC)
    Set F2 = Sheets(Fichier).Range("I1:I" & DernlistC)
    Dernligne = DernligneC
    End If
    
    
    j = 1
    For i = 2 To Dernligne
    If Not IsEmpty(ColumnA.Range("A" & i)) And IsEmpty(ColumnA.Range("C" & i)) Then
    ColumnA.Range("A" & i).Copy Sheets("Feuil1").Range("M" & j)
    j = j + 1
    End If
    Next i
    
    
    Sheets("Feuil1").Range("M1:M" & N).Copy Sheets("Feuil1").Range("K1")
    
    
    j = 1
    For i = 1 To Dernlist
    If F2.Range("A" & i) = Sheets("Feuil1").Range("K" & j) Then
    F2.Range("C" & i) = "Intervention en cours" & " " & Medecin & " " & Date
    j = j + 1
    End If
    Next i
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: "second time error 13 appears" does not say too much, I am afraid. Please, specify on which code line this error appears and in which circumstances. Only more than two columns in a specific sheet? Otherwise, nobody has enough time to waste for understanding a code which does not work as needed and only you know the need...

Comment: hello the message appears on this line DernligneA = Sheets(Fichier).Range("C3").End(xlDown).Rows + 1

Comment: First I fill in somme data in sheets1 then I launch the programm, it ru properly and execute the research but whem I lauch a second request that message appears at DernligneA = Sheets(Fichier).Range("C3").End(xlDown).Rows + 1

Comment: `DernligneA = Sheets(Fichier).Range("C3").End(xlDown).Rows + 1` will return a long built from the last cell value, before an empty cel, plus 1. If no C:C column exists, it will be 1. Such an error will occur only if the value of the last cell is a string, which cannot be added to 1... I do not think your problem is the missing column. Try checking the last cell on C:C column, at the second trial, to see if its value is not a string. Even 3 can be a string, in a wrong formatted cell...

Comment: Yes I also thing its a format pb on the last cell+1 but even when a put the sheet under numeric format is trigger same aerror at same line

Comment: I tried to replace DernligneA = Sheets(Fichier).Range("C3").End(xlDown).Rows + 1 by DernligneA = Sheets(Fichier).Range("C3").End(xlDown).Row + 1 (removing S from Rows) the error is no longer triggered but the programm run only on 2first lines from range no more taking into account quantity of interventions related to "N"

Comment: The two constructions return differently. The existing one return the **value** of the last cell and the new one returns the row of the last cell. So, I am sure the value in discussion is not a Long, even if you see it as a number. Try firstly formatting the cell as `General` and place there a value only after you did that. When you place the number is it aligned right or left?

Comment: number appear on the right

Comment: I just replaced Sheets(Fichier).Range("C3").End(xlDown).Rows + 1 by Sheets(Fichier).Range("C3").End(xlDown).Row + N and it works :)

Comment: Yes. `N` being a `Long` variable, VBA make conversion when it receives a value. You can also try `CLng(Sheets(Fichier).Range("C3").End(xlDown).Rows) + 1`, I think.